# VS 2013 Template renders different in Chrome and IE11

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4.5 app running.

It's using the default templates in VS 2013 Express - however when viewed in Chrome, it looks fine - when viewed in IE11 it looks broken.

Can anyone suggest a quick fix to get these two browsers to display the same with the default templates for VS?

[image: Chrome vs IE11]

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Use the browser tools to inspect the css - possibly the default values for some elements differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at using a reset style sheet to make sure that the defaults for all your elements are set to the same thing. Just type "reset css" into Google and then go with one you like the look of. You do this because each browser manufacturer generally implements slightly different defaults for their browsers, so unless you tell it otherwise it will apply these and this to your elements.

You also probably want to make sure that you have the box-model set for your browser sizing.

```
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```